# Limiting aggreation to the top X hits in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

ElasticSearch builds the aggregation results based on all the hits of the query independently of the from and size parameters. This is what we want in most cases, but I have a particular case in which I need to limit the aggregation to the top N hits. The limits filter is not suitable as it does not fetch the best N items but only the first X matching the query (per shard) independently of their score.

Is there any way to build a query whose hit count has an upper limit N in order to be able to build an aggregation limited to those top N results? And if so how?

**Subsidiary question:** Limiting the score of matching documents could be an alternative even though in my case I would require a fixed bound. Does the min_score parameter affect aggregation?

Comment: How did you end up doing this? I have the exact same issue and would be very glad about any hints how to achieve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Sampler Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html).

I have a similar answer explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896043/limit-elasticsearch-aggregation-to-top-n-query-results/35971531#35971531)

> Optionally, you can use the field or script and max_docs_per_value
>   settings to control the maximum number of documents collected on any
>   one shard which share a common value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ElasticSearch cluster with version > 1.3, you can use **top_hits aggregation** by nesting it in your aggregation, ordering on the field you want and set the `size` parameter to X.

The related documentation can be found [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation).

Comment: From what I understand from the documentation, this does really resolve my case. I want to aggregate on the top hits of my scope query, not access the top hits of each bucket (which is what the top_hits aggregation provides).

Comment: Exactly; if you could then have a sub-aggregation of the top_hits aggregation, it could be working. But for some reason the top_hits aggregation does not accept sub aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to limit the aggregation to the top N hits

With nested aggregations, your top bucket can represent those N hits, with nested aggregations operating on that bucket. I would try a `filter` aggregation for the top level aggregation.

The tricky part is to make use the of `_score` somehow in the filter and to limit it exactly to N entries... There is a [`limit`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-limit-filter.html) filter that works per shard, but I don't think it would work in this context.

Comment: The limit filter will indeed not work because it only stops at the first X documents matching the query independently of their score which I need to be taken into account.

Comment: For the filter aggregation I would need a top_hits filter... but that doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Sampler Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html) can now be used for this purpose. Note that it is only available as of Elastic 2.0.