# Aggregate over last documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm a bit new to ES and I'm not sure how to do the following:

I run a search with a query which will only contain a few 'should' parameters.

Then also a few aggregations, e.g. a percentile, term bucketing, etc.

But for the aggregations, I only want it, e.g., aggregated over the first 1000 documents (which I hope is then scored and ordered by the score).

The idea is that I want the aggs for specific terms, but if not enough are found, then fill it up - but limited to a specific max number to aggregate on. From the docs it seems that `size` is the number of documents it returns, not the size that will be used for the aggs (I do not need hits, only aggs returned).

So how do I go about this? Is there a nested/subsequent query? Must I `pipeline` something, e.g. get the search for 1k docs, then agg that?

It would be ideal if the documents could first be sorted by the timestamp it was indexed - so that the documents that is used to 'fill up' are the latest - but AFAIK that is not possible?

**Fill it up?**

'fill it up' means I have 100 docs for one specified 'should' field specified. Then I still need the other 900 docs for the required the 1k result size to aggregate over (so to fill it up to the number required). So instead of using a filter I saw the 'combined queries' in the docs and I think using a 'should' parameter would suffice.

Comment: Can clarify what you mean by "fill it up"? Perhaps by including a json example of what you expect?

Comment: @Phil edited question

Comment: this might help. A filter with limit - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29127328/689625

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
        sample = A('sampler', shard_size=docs_per_shard)
```

In order to aggregate over a subset of documents, use the Sampler aggregator. That returns a subset of the documents. It requires a shard_size parameter which is how many docs per shard it must return. The value given is the required docs size (100) divided by the active shards (5).

```
        terms = A('terms', field='action')
        sea = GameAction.search()
        sea.aggs.bucket('mesam', sample).bucket('aksies', terms)
```

Having the subsample, it can now be aggregated by piping it. This gives the solution, but lets make it even better.

```
        sea = sea.sort('_score', {'created_at': 'desc'})
```

This will sort the docs by score and then by created date, meaning the most relevant docs are returned AND it is ordered giving the most recent first.

Furthermore:

```
        sea = sea.query('bool', boost=10, should=[Q('match', player=p['name'])])
        sea = sea.query('bool', boost=5, should=[Q('match', vs=vs)])
        sea = sea.query('bool', boost=2, should=[Q('match', phase=phase)])
        sea = sea.query('bool', boost=1, should=[Q('match', site='handhq')])
        sea = sea.query('bool', must=[
            ~Q('match', action='gg') &
            ~Q('match', action='sb') &
            ~Q('match', action='bb')])
```

Relevant here is the `should`. This allows the documents to be 'filled up' with *most relevant* docs where it matches or closely matched (and being sorted with latest where equal). These fields are mostly `not_analyzed`. Also, it can be boosted giving a very good solution to the problem.