# Aggregation only on top N documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query which include a `function_score`, I would like to execute the `aggregations` only on the first `N` elements ( sorted per `_score` ).

It is possible ? how ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896043/limit-elasticsearch-aggregation-to-top-n-query-results) can help you.

Comment: `shard_size` is limiting the quantity per shard. not total

Comment: so I tried for `shard_size:1` and added a `min`/ `max` in my `aggregations` , the `min` , `max` doesnt match the documents returned in the `hits` so it is not using the `_score` to sort before doing the aggregations :/

Comment: The only thing I found is `min_score` but it is hard to have a hard coded threshold like that.