# Limit The Number Of Results Processed By An Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query with an aggregation. I want the aggregation to only operate on the top 500 hits returned by the query.

For example, let's say I have an index of comments. I want to query the top 500 matching comments and aggregate them based on the poster, so that I may answer the question: "Who are the top kitten and puppy posters?".

The query might look something like this:

```
POST comments/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "\"kittens\" OR \"puppies\"",
          "default_field": "body"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "posters": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "poster"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is, as far as I know, the aggregation will operate on **ALL** returned results, not the top 500.

Things I've Already Tried/Considered:

- `size` at the query root only changes the number of hits returned by
  the query, but has no effect on the aggregation.
- `size` inside the
  terms aggregation only affects the total number of buckets to return.
- There used to be a `limit` filter in older versions that would limit the number of hits returned by a query (and therefore the number processed by the aggregation) but that was deprecated in favor of...
- `terminate-after` which doesn't work because the results aren't sorted by score before being returned so I couldn't get the **top** 500, just a set of 500

Does anyone know how to limit the documents processed by an aggregation to only the **top** results?

EDIT: I'm using ES version 6.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit ElasticSearch aggregation to top n query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896043/limit-elasticsearch-aggregation-to-top-n-query-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [sampler aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html). You will have to wrap your `poster` aggregation into the sample aggregation.

The `shard_size` parameter is number of document that will be considered for the subaggregation. In your case 500.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "\"kittens\" OR \"puppies\"",
          "default_field": "body"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "sample": {
            "sampler": {
                "shard_size": 500
            },
            "aggs": {
                "posters": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "poster"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is exactly it! Thank you.

Comment: Looks like I can't award you the bounty until tomorrow :(. I'll do my best to remember to do it then.