# Elasticsearch aggregation by max date giving wrong results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to group by `sysCode` by max `date` that is get the latest documents for each `sysCode` and then aggregate on `employeeId` and type field.
The below query does not return me desired results, for `GER` it returns `employeeId=1` and for `IND` it returns `employeeId=3` which I do not want.

**sample json document**

```json
{
  "sysCode": "GER",
  "employeeId": 1,
  "date": "2014-06-14",
  "categories": {
    "pb": [
      {
        "metric": "OVERDUE",
        "type": "LATE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "sysCode": "GER",
  "employeeId": 2,
  "date": "2014-06-15",
  "categories": {
    "pb": [
      {
        "metric": "OVERDUE",
        "type": "LATE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "sysCode": "IND",
  "employeeId": 3,
  "date": "2014-06-16",
  "categories": {
    "pb": [
      {
        "metric": "OVERDUE",
        "type": "LATE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "sysCode": "IND",
  "employeeId": 3,
  "date": "2014-06-16",
  "categories": {
    "pb": [
      {
        "metric": "OVERDUE",
        "type": "MISSED"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**aggregation query**

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "result_by_sys_code": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "sysCode"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_as_of_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "date"
          }
        },
        "employees": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "employeeId"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "nested": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "categories.pb"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "metrics": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "categories.pb.type.keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**mappings**

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "categories": {
        "properties": {
          "pb": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "metric": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "type": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "controlCode": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add your mappings here

Comment: added field mappings

Comment: since your date is of the format `yyyy-mm-dd`, what do you plan to do in case of multiple documents having same date (which IMHO will be a more often than not case)?

Answer (score 0):

I think using [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html), you can fulfil your requirement.
From the official documentation:

> This aggregator is intended to be used as a sub aggregator, so that the top matching documents can be aggregated per bucket.

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/sales/_search?size=0&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "aggs": {
    "top_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type",
        "size": 3
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_sales_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "date": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [ "date", "price" ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

*we group the sales by type and per type we show the last sale. For each sale only the date and price fields are being included in the source.*

Also, [Sampler Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html) do something similar but in a different way.

> A filtering aggregation used to limit any sub aggregations' processing to a sample of the top-scoring documents.

Can refer [Limit ElasticSearch aggregation to top n query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896043/limit-elasticsearch-aggregation-to-top-n-query-results) for a TL;DR on Sampler.

Comment: In my case I need to sub aggregate on the top most hit,is this possible here?

Comment: pardon? I did not understand